# Averaging rows based upon a known, irregular relationship using R

Tags: r

I have data on energy companies whose jurisdiction overlaps in places. I want to be able to compute an average of sales for the places where these companies overlap. These companies will always overlap - so how can I use this information to calculate the averages just for those pairs? There are about 20 pairs of companies.

```
data <- data.frame(Company = c("Energy USA","Good Energy",
                             "Hydropower 4 U",
                             "Coal Town",
                             "Energy USA/Good Energy",
                             "Good Energy/Coal Town"),
                   Sales = c(100, 2500, 550, 6000, "?", "?"))

Company                      Sales
1   Energy USA               100
2   Good Energy              2500
3   Hydropower 4 U           550
4   Coal Town                6000
5   Energy USA/Good Energy   ? (Answer: 1300)
6   Good Energy/Coal Town    ? (Answer: 4250)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use 'grep' to get index of 'Company' elements that have more than one entries i.e. separated by '/'.  Then, split those elements by the delimiter (output will be a `list`), loop through the `list` with `sapply`, `match` the elements with the 'Company' column to get the position, use that to get the corresponding 'Sales' elements.  As the 'Sales' column was `factor`, we need to convert it to `numeric` to get the `mean`.  When we convert `factor` to `numeric` class, all non-numeric elements i.e. `?` will be converted to `NA`.  Replace those `NA` elements with the `mean` values.

```
i1 <- grepl('/', data$Company)
v1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Company[i1]), '/'), 
    function(x) mean(as.numeric(as.character(data$Sales[match(x,
                    data$Company)]))))
data$Sales <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Sales))
data$Sales[is.na(data$Sales)] <- v1
data
#                 Company Sales
#1             Energy USA   100
#2            Good Energy  2500
#3         Hydropower 4 U   550
#4              Coal Town  6000
#5 Energy USA/Good Energy  1300
#6  Good Energy/Coal Town  4250
```

Comment: +1 - This answer leapfrogged over my erroneous assumption that it would even be helpful to know in advance what elements overlap. It is much easier to rely on the backslash, especially if the companies change in the future. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your original data is, it is hard to give a working answer. However, assuming your data has Company and Sales columns with multiple rows for each company, you can do something like this:

```
mean(data$Sales[data$Company %in% c('Energy USA', 'Good Energy')]])
mean(data$Sales[data$Company %in% c('Good Energy', 'Coal Town')]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you could create a new column "jurisdiction" in "data", if your dataset is rather small..

```
MeansByJurisdiction <- tapply(data$sales, data$jurisdiction, mean)
```

then you could convert the vector to dataframe

```
MeansByJurisdiction <- data.frame(MeansByJurisdiction)
```

the rownames in the `MeansByJurisdiction` dataframe will be populated with the jurisdictions and you can extract them with a simple line of code:

```
MeansByJurisdiction$jurisdictions <- row.names(MeansByJurisdiction)
```